# Fastest way to find two minimum values in each column of NumPy array

Tags: numpy, min

If I want to find the minimum value in each column of a NumPy array, I can use the numpy.amin() function. However, is there a way to find the two minimum values in each column, that is faster than sorting each column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`np.partition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) along the columns to get smallest `N` numbers -

```
N = 2
np.partition(a,kth=N-1,axis=0)[:N]
```

This doesn't actually sort the entire data, simply partitions into two *sections* such that smallest N numbers are in the first *section*, also called as `partial-sort`.

**Bonus (Getting top N elements) :** Similarly, to get the top `N` numbers per col, simply use negative `kth` value -

```
np.partition(a,kth=-N,axis=0)[-N:]
```

**Along other axes and higher dim arrays**

To use it along other axes, change the `axis` value. So, along rows, it would be `axis=1` for a 2D array and extend the same way for higher dimension ndarrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use the min() method, and specify the axis you want to average over:

```
a = np.random.rand(10,3)
a.min(axis=0)
```

gives:

```
array([0.04435587, 0.00163139, 0.06327353])


a.min(axis=1)
```

gives

```
array([0.01354386, 0.08996586, 0.19332211, 0.00163139, 0.55650945,
       0.08409907, 0.23015718, 0.31463493, 0.49117553, 0.53646868])
```

Comment: The problem was, I wanted the two smallest values per column, not just the minimum of each column. I didn't want to sort each column, since that seemed too computationally expensive. I wasn't aware of NumPy's partition function, which does exactly what I need.

Comment: Ah ok - gotcha!